# ACPI thermal zone \_TZ.TZ01 has been enumerated

Tags: windows, windows-11, crash, events

I get this error immediately before my Laptop hard shuts down (just cuts out, no boot down sequence). It then re-boots and all is well again?

Windows event log:

```
ACPI thermal zone \_TZ.TZ01 has been enumerated.             
_PSV = 0K             
_TC1 = 1             
_TC2 = 2             
_TSP = 2000ms             
_AC0 = 0K             
_AC1 = 0K             
_AC2 = 0K             
_AC3 = 0K             
_AC4 = 0K             
_AC5 = 0K             
_AC6 = 0K             
_AC7 = 0K             
_AC8 = 0K             
_AC9 = 0K             
_CRT = 393K             
_HOT = 0K             
minimum throttle = 0             
_CR3 = 0K
```

This is followed by: "Critical: Kernel-Power"

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>9</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-11-20T08:14:23.6318011Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>35591</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Oriel</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">1</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">1</Data> 
  <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="LidReliability">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="InputSuppressionState">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonSuppressionState">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="LidState">1</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

The laptop has a full battery, it is a very new laptop (4 weeks). I was only browsing the web at the time, nothing intensive, as far as I can tell it didn't over-heat, it wasn't hot to the touch as it would be if I was gaming.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The ACPI thermal zone seems to be informative only and does not
contain an error message, so by itself is not very helpful.

The "Critical: Kernel-Power" event 41 is also not very helpful.
See the Microsoft article
[Advanced troubleshooting for Event ID 41: "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/event-id-41-restart).

If the abrupt shutdown is not related to power cuts or surges,
this might be a hardware problem.

The first likely one is a heating problem. You should install software
that can monitor your temperature, such as
[Core Temp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/).
See also the article
[How to Check and Monitor Your CPU Temperature](https://www.avast.com/c-how-to-check-cpu-temperature).

For a general checkup of your RAM and more, run
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
for many hours or even over-night.